# How do I configure __init__.py in this situation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python application with the following structure.

```
/app
  /models
    __init__.py
    profile.py
  /views
    __init__.py
    index.py
    login.py
  __init.py
main.py
```

Currently the three `__init__.py` files are empty.

In the files like `index.py`, I have several classes.

```
class IndexHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #blah blah
```

What do I write in the `__init.py__` files such that I can call the classes in `profile.py`, `index.py` and so on without typing the full package path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces in Python are explicit. In each `__init__.py` file, import whatever modules, functions, and classes you would like to be available within the namespace of that package.

For example, if you would like the `app` package to have an `index` member, in `/app/__init__.py`:

```
from views import index
```

Or if you would like the class itself to be part of the namespace:

```
from models.views import IndexHandler
```

This will allow you to do:

```
import app
handler1 = app.index.IndexHandler()  # example 1
handler1 = app.IndexHandler()  # example 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You technically don't have to put anything in the `__init__.py` file. You should be able to import models from your `main.py` file, as long as it is in the app folder, and use the functions like:

```
import models    
models.profile.whatever
```

If you `main.py` is 'above' your /app folder, you will need an `__init__.py` file in your /app folder. then you can do:

```
import app
app.models.profile.whatever
```

Comment: Yes, I got that. I want to call the classes contained within the subpackage from main.py directly without specifying the full package path.

Comment: You can always do `from app.models.profile import whatever` then do `whatever()`